# How to use run_flow() in Google Calendar API?

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to authenticate to Google Calendar API reusing [the sample described in the docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/get_started):

```
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

CLIENT_SECRETS = 'client_secrets.json'
FLOW = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
                                      scope=[
                                          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                                          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
                                      ],
                                      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS))

storage = file.Storage('sample.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(FLOW, storage, auth_host_name='localhost', auth_host_port=[8080, 8090],
                                 logging_level='ERROR', noauth_local_webserver=False)
```

This code fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/infoscreen/testgoogle.py", line 18, in <module>
    logging_level='ERROR', noauth_local_webserver=False)
  File "C:\infoscreen\oauth2client\util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: run_flow() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_host_name'
```

The [documentation for `run-flow()`](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.tools-module.html#run_flow) says that

> It presumes it is run from a command-line application and supports the
>   following flags:
>
> --auth_host_name: Host name to use when running a local web server
>       to handle redirects during OAuth authorization.
>       (default: 'localhost')

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a month late but I'll give it a go.

I took a look at the docs and found this under the flags sections:

```
The tools module defines an ArgumentParser the already contains the flag
definitions that run() requires. You can pass that ArgumentParser to your
ArgumentParser constructor:

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[tools.run_parser])
flags = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

So it seems as though you shouldn't add the flags as arguments but add them from the command line and then use Google's `ArgumentParser` to return a "flags" object, which is then added as the third positional argument.

Answer (score 4):

The run_flow() function is controlled by command-line flags, and the Python standard library argparse module must be initialized, the following shows how to use it:

```
import argparse
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage

client_id = 'YOUR CLIENT IS HERE'
client_secret = 'YOU CLIENT SECRET IS HERE'
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, scope)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args()

storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
#the get() function returns the credentials for the Storage object. 

credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
```